# Curses::UI::Grid module

Tags: perl, perl-module, ncurses

This is first example from perldoc

```
use Curses::UI;
my $cui = new Curses::UI;
my $win = $cui->add('window_id', 'Window');
my $grid =$win->add(
  'mygrid', 'Grid'
  -rows    => 3,
  -columns => 5,
);

# set header desc 
$grid->set_label("cell$_", "Head $_")
  for (1 .. 5);

# add some data
$grid->set_cell_value("row1", "cell$_", "value $_")
  for 1 .. 5;
my $val = $grid->get_value("row1", "cell2");
```

which gives me this fatal eror

```
  Fatal program error:
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Could not load Curses::UI::0 from Curses/UI/0.pm:
  Can't locate Curses/UI/0.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/sha
  re/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 .) at /usr/share/perl5/Curses/UI.pm line 846.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Press any key to exit...
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Did you install [Curses::UI](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI.pm)? If you did, you should check the paths so that this lib is visible to perl.

Comment: @DmitryMina yes I did, but I don't have Curses/UI/0.pm on my system. And Curses::UI::0 looks odd for module name.

Comment: Just ran into this exact problem. Adding the missing comma after `'Grid'` seems to solve at least *part of* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got this fixed on my machine. You need to install the following packages:

```
sudo cpan -fi Curses::UI::Widget
sudo cpan -fi Curses::UI::Grid
```

If you already did install them as well, you should try it again, because I also thought that I installed them, but eventually it appeared that I did not do it properly at first and I've got the same errors as you did. Now everything works, hope it will help you.

Comment: Tnx; it seems that's something wrong with my machine as it still gives me same error.